# Contact Form 7 Text Fields not editable

Tags: wordpress, input, zurb-foundation, contact-form-7

I am trying to use contact form 7 to create a custom–styled form. I am using WP Joints theme with foundation.

The first 4 fields are not editable in chrome or firefox, but  the comment field is. All fields work in IE (strangely enough). What am I doing that is causing this? The styling needs to be this way for a client but I am probably using certain CSS that is altering the final product.

[Link to the site](http://delindesign.com/adlhochgroup/contact/)

HERE IS THE CSS

```
#contact-bb {
    background-image: url("http://delindesign.com/adlhochgroup/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/contact-bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:0% 30%;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.contact-header {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: #8ca408;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3rem 0 3rem 0;
    }

#first_margin {
margin-bottom:.5rem !important; 
    }

#comments_margin {
padding-top:.5rem !important;   
    }


.wpcf7-email {
margin-bottom: .5rem !important;
}


.wpcf7-text {
background-color: #efefef;
}

.wpcf7-textarea {
background-color: #efefef;
}
.wpcf7-submit {
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
border: none;
padding: .5rem 4rem .5rem 4rem;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
background-color: #8ca408; 
}


span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip { display: inline !important;}

#cf7-left {
    padding: 0 .5rem .5rem 0 !important;
}

#cf7-right {
    padding: 0 0 .5rem 0 !important;
}
.wpcf7-text {
    margin-bottom:0;
}



#no-pad {
    padding:0 !important;
    }

.pad-left-1c {
    padding-left: 5rem;
        }

.bold-contact {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    line-height: 1.33;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    }



    #contact-padding{
    padding-top: 1.8rem !important;
    }

    .reg-contact {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 1.33;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    }
```

and the form

```
<div id="cf7-left" class="large-6 small-6 columns">
            [text* firstname placeholder id:first_margin akismet:author "First Name"]
            [text lastname placeholder "Last Name"]
        </div>

        <div id="cf7-right" class="large-6 small-6 columns">
            [email email placeholder "Email"]
            [text company placeholder "Company"]
        </div>


<div class="large-12 pad-top">
        [textarea* comments placeholder id:comments_margin "Comments"]
        [submit id:submit-button "Submit"]
    </div>
```

Comment: Visiting your link I am able to edit all inputs.  I am using Chrome 53 on Windows 10.

Comment: My mistake—I fixed it and did not update this. The problem was my putting them in foundation rows and tables. My solution was just making a div with display: table and making the fields 50% width table cells. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my putting them in foundation rows and tables. The fields in foundation were editable. My solution was just making a div with display: table and making the fields 50% width table cells float left. It has worked across all browsers so far.